# how to filter out the initial value but all the subsequent ones?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

This `notificationsCount$` is being called by several components. That's why I make one initial call the first time a component want to read the data.

```
this.initialLoad = false;    

readonly notificationsCount$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(getNotificationsCount),
  tap(() => {
    if(!this.initialLoad){
       this.initialLoad = true;
       this.loadNotifications();
    }
  }),
  skip(1)
);
```

without filtering, the selector is returning **0**, the initial value, and **3**, the number of notifications after the call was made to backend. I want the selector to emit every value but the initial one, i.e. **0**.

skip(0) still returns both values, i.e. 0 and 3. skip(1) returns 0. skip(2) doesn't return anything.

Thanks for helping

Comment: It seems like `skip(1)` should work.  However, if there are multiple subscriptions, the first emission to late subscribers may be the correct one (*meaning you don't want to skip any*).  Try putting [`shareReplay()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) after your `skip(1)`.  If that works, you can probably get rid of the `if` inside the `tap` and simply do `tap(() => this.loadNotifications())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is index argument you can `mergeMap/switchMap` to count the emission and depend on the index you can swallow the emission with `never()`

```
this.store.pipe(mergeMap((value,index)=>{
if(index<1) return never()
// do you stuff 
}))
```